# Error creating new EcoSpace - "Model not Ecoified"

Tags: mdriven

So, I have some MDriven Eco classes to be used/called from a Rhino/Grasshopper (GH) component for creating CAD-geometry.

My original (and well tested) C# code was moved from the GH-component into EcoClasses, So now, from the GH-component I need to create an EcoSpace and create a first Eco class (say, EcoAppKernel) which can then create the rest of the (Eco) objects in my system.

My eco package is (re)named "EcoClasses", and so I assumed I could just create an eco space likes so:

```
    EcoSpace ecoSpace = new EcoClassesEcoSpace(); // #Error! "...not Ecoified"
    ecoSpace.Active = true; 
    // etc
```

and with that I would create the first eco object:

```
    public EcoAppKernel CreateAppKernel()
    {
        var intfs = ecoSpace.ObjectFactory.CreateNewObject("EcoAppKernel");
        return intf.AsObject as EcoAppKernel;
    }

    EcoAppKernel _kernel = CreateAppKernel();
    etc
```

The instantiation of the EcoSpace fails with the error message `"Model not Ecoified ..."`

This is the first time I call a MDriven dll from another app (from inside a Rhino Grasshopper component in this case) so really do need some advice.

//Rolf

[image: Grasshopper Component complaining...]

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question completely but the message "...not Ecoified" normally means that there are changes in the MDriven data model that are not yet represented in the currently generated code.

Regenerate the C# code and rebuild the project. Normally this should solve the problem.

Comment: The code is (re-)generated since the last model changes, and it compiles. So I get this error "not Ecoified" in runtime. I have no idea what "Ecoified"  means, and a search on the Internet gives no hits.
Could it be related to a non-Eco field (a field of type Brep[], which is a CAD binary representations of surfaces)? If so, how do I define a non-Eco field as to not confuse the MDriven Framework with unknown field types? (I asked this in another post).

Comment: Yes. You get the message only in runtime and indeed it can also mean: There is a property that is not compliant with Modlr/Mdriven rules. There is also a button in the Modlr that can check if the model is Ok.